# How do I style my user registration form using Bootstrap in DJango?

Tags: django

So I have the following user registration form which I want to style. My forms.py look something like this. :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password']
```

Now this is my views.py:

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class =UserForm
    template_name = 'visit/registration/register.html'

    def get(self,request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user =form.save(commit=False)

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:

                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect('visit:index')


        return render(request, 'visit/registration/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Now What I am getting a bit confused in HTML, since there is only one line which passes all these fields in the page together. So how M I supposed to style these fields separately.

```
{% extends 'visit/base.html'%}

{%block content%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% static "visit/registration.css"%}">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" class = "sign-up-form">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options, each one with its pros and cons:

**1. Add custom css classes within `forms.py`**

To use the simplicity of `{{ form.as_p }}` approach you could manually add classes to all your forms fields, e.g.:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class' : 'your-custom-class'})
    )
```

Note that it could be a challenge to render the form to be perfectly aligned with Bootstrap's style.

**2. Render the form manually**

You could write your form by hand within your template, e.g.:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}">
    {% trans 'Password' %}
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}"
         name="{{ form.password.html_name }}"
         {% if form.password.field.required %}required{% endif %}
         class="form-control{% if form.password.errors %} is-invalid{% endif %}"
         value="{% if form.password.value %}{{ form.password.value }}{% endif %}">
  {% if form.password.help_text %}
    <small class="text-muted">
      {{ form.password.help_text }}
    </small>
  {% endif %}
  {% for err in form.password.errors %}
    <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ err }}</span>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

More info on rendering form fields manually can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

The above snippet will use most of the functionality existing in the default django [form renders methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates), but on the other hand forces you to write a lot of boilerplate code which is harden to maintain in the long run.

**3. Use 3rd party app as a mix of the first two options**

You could use custom app to handle the rendering of the forms, a good example would be [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: The link to Django's documentations is now invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [django-bootstrap](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3)
This will automatically render the bootstrap form for you.

```
{% extends 'visit/base.html'%}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{%block content%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% static "visit/registration.css"%}">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" class = "sign-up-form">

        {% csrf_token %} 
        {% bootstrap_form form %}

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
{%endblock%}
```